# Delete log file when exceeds size limit every minute. Crontab/Logrotate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, logrotate, log-rotation

Currently it deletes all the log files that starts with laravel-*.log instead of the ones that are bigger then 100MB. My logrotate version is 3.8.7.

My crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * root logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/laravel.conf
```

laravel.conf:

```
/var/www/html/project/storage/logs/laravel-*.log {
        su root adm
        rotate 0
        size 100M
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by removing -f. Now it doesn't ignore my requirements, of course.